# Cats and dogs in microgravity; how much information is there on their locomotive ability or adaptability in space? Is there anything at all?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, astronaut-lifestyle, animals, tourism

Cats and dogs are both known to be very popular pets for humans around the world and have been bred for thousands of years for this purpose.

Destin Sandlin's [Slow Motion Flipping Cat Physics | Smarter Every Day 58](https://youtu.be/RtWbpyjJqrU) includes footage of cats momentarily floating and flailing in aircraft in parabolic flight, and early Soviet spaceflight tests have included dogs in seat belts.

**Question:** But is there any information at all on the locomotive ability or adaptability of cats and dogs in space? If so, how much?

"Locomotive adaptability" means can they figure out how to move around in some way, given some time. Without the ability to get from point A to point B when they want to, the experience may be quite stressful and they would have to be hand-fed and waste would end up everywhere.

**For example:** mice seem to have "locomotive adaptability" in that they can work out how to move around. I don't think they were hand-fed the whole time.

From [How would a mousetrap for use in space work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35600/12102)

> [image: Screenshots from "Mice aboard the International Space Station" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7lgj3aZ8dU]
>
> Screenshots from [Mice aboard the International Space Station](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7lgj3aZ8dU)

See also [If mice escaped on the International Space Station, could they live and thrive?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35562/12102)

---

Related but different: [What animals would be best suited as pets or comfort animals for extended periods of spaceflight in microgravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54252/12102)

---

From Gizmodo's [This Wifi-Enabled Space Toilet for Cats Turned Me Into a Kitty Garbage Man, As God Intended](https://gizmodo.com/this-wifi-enabled-space-toilet-for-cats-turned-me-into-1847303337)

[image: From Gizmodo's "This Wifi-Enabled Space Toilet for Cats Turned Me Into a Kitty Garbage Man, As God Intended" https://gizmodo.com/this-wifi-enabled-space-toilet-for-cats-turned-me-into-1847303337]

The story describes a test of this waste management system for cats. While the title suggests it's a "space toilet" the principle requires gravity to be present. Thus it has been added to illustrate the problem associated with waste management rather than a solution to it. I have no affiliation with this nor any other space-cat product.

Comment: Cats (and to lesser extent dogs) adapt well to variable environment, both did quite well on old wooden ships, even in storms. But as for zero-g? Both dogs and cats have been to space, but only in restrained environments (Laika and others russian dogs, Félicette the french cat). So....insufficient data? Or maybe I've missed an experiment where a cat or dog was allowed running space in space.

Comment: @PcMan I never knew there had been a cat in space, so I've learned something already!

Comment: @PcMan: thanks for  reminding me about [Félicette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9licette).

Comment: I agree with @PcMan, adaptability on earth doesn't mean adaptability in zero g, and there isn't enough information to say.

Comment: @GdD if it's pretty certain that there's no information on this (e.g. nobody has brought a dog or cat into parabolic flight enough times to show that it can learn how to deal with the problem), then it may serve as the answer to the question for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Not much room for movement for Félicette in [this contraption](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4073/4769819469_0674ac3943_b.jpg) & [this](http://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/449d4618ee02d68ecf7a145551857d65)

Comment: waste management. uuugh... and mice infestations? even more uuughhh... and thats just on Earth...

Comment: @blobbymcblobby I've added a reference to waste management at the end

Comment: lol! Not seen that before! Having had cats before, when they do their stuff, and they scratch around - that doesn't bear thinking about even inside a toilet bubble! I can imagine a pet would be very wary of even a vacuum suction funnel sucking their bits out! And even the bubble - unless it was a mini airlock - could not hide the smell of pets in general in such an enclosed environment..

Comment: The first monkey cages habitat flown on shuttle failed to contain the inhabitants' waste much to the crew's disgust.

Comment: A cat would survive a short (some day) long space travel. Unlikely that it would travel again on its own will. Unlikely that any human traveling with it would travel again with a cat on his own will. Waste management in weightlessness for cats is impossible. Totally impossible. You can not explain to them, how to use a space wc. On a space station, little cats could be trained to use one, but it would be hard and take months. Anyways they could adapt weightlessness easily, but they would hate it. You could not explain to them that they are not falling.